# Mantener la posicion de un RecyclerView cuando agrego datos

Tags: android, volley

Buenas tengo un problema que al agregar datos me envia al inicio del recycler cuando en realidad lo que quiero es que se mantenga en la posición actual. Esto sucede cada ves que el usuario llena al fin del pie vuelva a cargar mas datos desde volley  ..

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

el metodo que detecta que ha llegado al final

```
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(0)) {
                CargarContenido();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supongo que lo que intentas es algo parecido a los mensajes en un chat, cuando llega uno nuevo, este se queda en la posicion del ultimo.

Intenta con `mensajes.scrollToPosition(adaptador.getItemCount()-1);` en el Activity donde cargas los elementos de tu Recycler.

Comment: Perfecto me ha funcionado a la perfección .

Comment: A mi también me ha funcionado perfecto, gracias por la contribución.